# Mac OS X 10.7 can't ping/telnet localhost

Tags: networking, osx-lion, ping, localhost, telnet

I'm developing using django/postgresql on Mac OS X 10.7 and suddenly I am unable to access the test server through http://localhost:8000/. I can make it listen on 0.0.0.0:8000 and then it works...

Then I noticed problems with SABnzbd starting up. Whenever I try to start it, it dies and shuts down. The logs show

```
IOError: Port 8080 not bound on '127.0.0.1'
```

running `netstat -an | grep 8080` shows that there is nothing actually listening on port 8080.

I then tried to telnet and ping localhost. Neither work. When I telnet, I get:

```
$ telnet localhost
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
```

and it just hangs there.

When I try to ping I get the following:

```
$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
```

The weird thing is that when I telnet to port 80 it works!

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

My `/etc/hosts` file seems normal:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Is there any way for me to fix this problem or is it easiest for me to just wipe it and start again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac OS X Mountain Lion can't ping/telnet localhost. Point to a wrong public IP](http://superuser.com/questions/541961/mac-os-x-mountain-lion-cant-ping-telnet-localhost-point-to-a-wrong-public-ip)

Answer (score 2):

Most firewalls block ping requests now, my OSX Lion install had that behavior by default too.

Try browsing to http://localhost:80 if you can connect to port 80, and look what's running on that port. Also take look at your Sharing Preferences - there used to be a Web Site sharing feature, and that might be using port 80.

Also, try telnetting to localhost:8080, and see if you can connect (if you can, another app is using that port).

Try to open http://localhost:8080 in your browser then, to try to find out what program is running on that port.

Comment: I can't telnet localhost:8080 or get to http://localhost:8080, both hang there. From what I can see, the firewall is turned off. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have Little Snitch (or compareable) running - saw that behavior over here too when running that.

Comment: Nope, I don't even have it on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, this is caused by text-encoding problems; /etc/hosts looks ok but is actually in the wrong encoding.  See [Mac OS X Mountain Lion can't ping/telnet localhost. Point to a wrong public IP](https://superuser.com/questions/541961/mac-os-x-mountain-lion-cant-ping-telnet-localhost-point-to-a-wrong-public-ip)

Comment: The question includes command output that shows that "localhost" is getting resolved to `127.0.0.1` and `::1`, so that isn't the issue here.