# Mac computer receives ping but doesn't respond

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, mac

*This is also posted on the [Apple’s Support Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251991403).*

I found multiple similar questions but none of them helped me.

I have a home network with 2 machines connected to the Wi-Fi router. Ping from A to B fails on timeout. `tcpdump` shows that machine B does see the incoming requests. Ping from B to A works. Both machines run on Mac OS, **firewalls disabled**, tried connecting them using my Android phone's hotspot Wi-Fi with the same result.

I want to connect my laptop (MacBook) to the stationary PC (Mac mini) via remote desktop.

---

### Router

- Model = [Inteno DG400 Prime](https://www.intenogroup.com/products/gateways/dg400-prime/)
- IP = `192.168.1.1`
- AP Isolation = off

---

### MacBook

- OS = Catalina 10.15.6
- IP = `192.168.1.231`
- Firewall: off
- `ping` works on: `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `192.168.1.1` (router), `192.168.1.231` (itself)
- `ping` timeouts on: `192.168.1.185` (mac mini)
- `nslookup sams-mac-mini` successfully resolves to `192.168.1.185`

`netstat -rn`:

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0
169.254            link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1          link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1.1/32     link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1.1        20:1f:31:aa:e5:90  UHLWIir        en0   1190
192.168.1.185      3c:22:fb:a8:43:ed  UHLWI          en0    902
192.168.1.231/32   link#6             UCS            en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCS           en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en0
239.192.152.143    1:0:5e:40:98:8f    UHmLWI         en0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI         en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCS            en0      !

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
default                                 fe80::221f:31ff:feaa:e590%en0   UGc             en0
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcI          utun0
default                                 fe80::%utun1                    UGcI          utun1
default                                 fe80::%utun2                    UGcI          utun2
default                                 fe80::%utun3                    UGcI          utun3
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
2001:7d0:84b0:1580::/64                 link#6                          UC              en0
2001:7d0:84b0:1580:4bf:ddc7:25f2:30f1   3c:22:fb:40:fd:5d               UHL             lo0
2001:7d0:84b0:1580:7c49:fd29:22b:1ea2   3c:22:fb:a8:43:ed               UHLWIi          en0
2001:7d0:84b0:1580:817a:55f7:e052:2518  link#6                          UHLWI           en0
2001:7d0:84b0:1580:bd28:6e56:8081:20c1  3c:22:fb:40:fd:5d               UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en5/64                           link#4                          UCI             en5
fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5           ac:de:48:0:11:22                UHLI            lo0
fe80::aede:48ff:fe33:4455%en5           ac:de:48:33:44:55               UHLWIi          en5
fe80::%en0/64                           link#6                          UCI             en0
fe80::c3d:9dc9:9593:12c8%en0            3c:22:fb:40:fd:5d               UHLI            lo0
fe80::1477:d6f9:e406:2a44%en0           3c:22:fb:a8:43:ed               UHLWI           en0
fe80::1826:bd30:ffca:e2af%en0           88:a9:b7:65:a0:4b               UHLWI           en0
fe80::221f:31ff:feaa:e590%en0           20:1f:31:aa:e5:90               UHLWIir         en0
fe80::%awdl0/64                         link#13                         UCI           awdl0
fe80::44ad:a1ff:febb:3021%awdl0         46:ad:a1:bb:30:21               UHLWIi        awdl0
fe80::a861:11ff:fea8:3756%awdl0         aa:61:11:a8:37:56               UHLI            lo0
fe80::%llw0/64                          link#14                         UCI            llw0
fe80::44ad:a1ff:febb:3021%llw0          46:ad:a1:bb:30:21               UHLWI          llw0
fe80::a861:11ff:fea8:3756%llw0          aa:61:11:a8:37:56               UHLI            lo0
fe80::%utun0/64                         fe80::e39:7f8:b2fb:4473%utun0   UcI           utun0
fe80::e39:7f8:b2fb:4473%utun0           link#15                         UHLI            lo0
fe80::%utun1/64                         fe80::245e:5d7e:31eb:6ac6%utun1 UcI           utun1
fe80::245e:5d7e:31eb:6ac6%utun1         link#16                         UHLI            lo0
fe80::%utun2/64                         fe80::4175:99b7:91f2:1a2e%utun2 UcI           utun2
fe80::4175:99b7:91f2:1a2e%utun2         link#17                         UHLI            lo0
fe80::%utun3/64                         fe80::19bd:c7d7:c780:8e80%utun3 UcI           utun3
fe80::19bd:c7d7:c780:8e80%utun3         link#18                         UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en5/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en5
ff01::%en0/32                           link#6                          UmCI            en0
ff01::%awdl0/32                         link#13                         UmCI          awdl0
ff01::%llw0/32                          link#14                         UmCI           llw0
ff01::%utun0/32                         fe80::e39:7f8:b2fb:4473%utun0   UmCI          utun0
ff01::%utun1/32                         fe80::245e:5d7e:31eb:6ac6%utun1 UmCI          utun1
ff01::%utun2/32                         fe80::4175:99b7:91f2:1a2e%utun2 UmCI          utun2
ff01::%utun3/32                         fe80::19bd:c7d7:c780:8e80%utun3 UmCI          utun3
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en5/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en5
ff02::%en0/32                           link#6                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%awdl0/32                         link#13                         UmCI          awdl0
ff02::%llw0/32                          link#14                         UmCI           llw0
ff02::%utun0/32                         fe80::e39:7f8:b2fb:4473%utun0   UmCI          utun0
ff02::%utun1/32                         fe80::245e:5d7e:31eb:6ac6%utun1 UmCI          utun1
ff02::%utun2/32                         fe80::4175:99b7:91f2:1a2e%utun2 UmCI          utun2
ff02::%utun3/32                         fe80::19bd:c7d7:c780:8e80%utun3 UmCI          utun3
```

---

### Mac Mini

- OS = Catalina 10.15.6
- IP = `192.168.1.185`
- Firewall: off
- `ping` works on: `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `192.168.1.1` (router), `192.168.1.185` (itself), `192.168.1.231` (MacBook)
- `nslookup sams-mbp` successfully resolves to `192.168.1.231`

Note: I do have a VPN installed but it's not connected/used at the moment, so you might see something here related to that.

`netstat -rn`:

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           en1
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0
169.254            link#7             UCS            en1      !
192.168.1          link#7             UCS            en1      !
192.168.1.1/32     link#7             UCS            en1      !
192.168.1.1        20:1f:31:aa:e5:90  UHLWIir        en1   1196
192.168.1.185/32   link#7             UCS            en1      !
192.168.1.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI         en1      !
224.0.0/4          link#7             UmCS           en1      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en1
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI         en1
255.255.255.255/32 link#7             UCS            en1      !

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
default                                 fe80::221f:31ff:feaa:e590%en1   UGc             en1
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcI          utun0
default                                 fe80::%utun1                    UGcI          utun1
default                                 fe80::%utun2                    UGcI          utun2
default                                 fe80::%utun3                    UGcI          utun3
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
2001:7d0:84b0:1580::/64                 link#7                          UC              en1
2001:7d0:84b0:1580:1c09:ef76:fc0f:6787  3c:22:fb:a8:43:ed               UHL             lo0
2001:7d0:84b0:1580:409c:597b:219b:31cd  3c:22:fb:a8:43:ed               UHL             lo0
2001:7d0:84b0:1580:8d39:c6a:9520:65a8   link#7                          UHLWI           en1
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en6/64                           link#5                          UCI             en6
fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en6           ac:de:48:0:11:22                UHLI            lo0
fe80::aede:48ff:fe33:4455%en6           ac:de:48:33:44:55               UHLWIi          en6
fe80::%en1/64                           link#7                          UCI             en1
fe80::1477:d6f9:e406:2a44%en1           3c:22:fb:a8:43:ed               UHLI            lo0
fe80::221f:31ff:feaa:e590%en1           20:1f:31:aa:e5:90               UHLWIir         en1
fe80::%awdl0/64                         link#9                          UCI           awdl0
fe80::5892:a4ff:fe11:f46c%awdl0         5a:92:a4:11:f4:6c               UHLI            lo0
fe80::a861:11ff:fea8:3756%awdl0         aa:61:11:a8:37:56               UHLWIi        awdl0
fe80::%llw0/64                          link#10                         UCI            llw0
fe80::5892:a4ff:fe11:f46c%llw0          5a:92:a4:11:f4:6c               UHLI            lo0
fe80::a861:11ff:fea8:3756%llw0          aa:61:11:a8:37:56               UHLWI          llw0
fe80::%utun0/64                         fe80::35c8:509b:4d5f:e060%utun0 UcI           utun0
fe80::35c8:509b:4d5f:e060%utun0         link#16                         UHLI            lo0
fe80::%utun1/64                         fe80::f4f5:d2b6:c69e:755e%utun1 UcI           utun1
fe80::f4f5:d2b6:c69e:755e%utun1         link#17                         UHLI            lo0
fe80::%utun2/64                         fe80::19c4:e545:e84:a3bc%utun2  UcI           utun2
fe80::19c4:e545:e84:a3bc%utun2          link#18                         UHLI            lo0
fe80::%utun3/64                         fe80::f9fd:1490:c5f0:37ef%utun3 UcI           utun3
fe80::f9fd:1490:c5f0:37ef%utun3         link#20                         UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff01::%en6/32                           link#5                          UmCI            en6
ff01::%en1/32                           link#7                          UmCI            en1
ff01::%awdl0/32                         link#9                          UmCI          awdl0
ff01::%llw0/32                          link#10                         UmCI           llw0
ff01::%utun0/32                         fe80::35c8:509b:4d5f:e060%utun0 UmCI          utun0
ff01::%utun1/32                         fe80::f4f5:d2b6:c69e:755e%utun1 UmCI          utun1
ff01::%utun2/32                         fe80::19c4:e545:e84:a3bc%utun2  UmCI          utun2
ff01::%utun3/32                         fe80::f9fd:1490:c5f0:37ef%utun3 UmCI          utun3
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%en6/32                           link#5                          UmCI            en6
ff02::%en1/32                           link#7                          UmCI            en1
ff02::%awdl0/32                         link#9                          UmCI          awdl0
ff02::%llw0/32                          link#10                         UmCI           llw0
ff02::%utun0/32                         fe80::35c8:509b:4d5f:e060%utun0 UmCI          utun0
ff02::%utun1/32                         fe80::f4f5:d2b6:c69e:755e%utun1 UmCI          utun1
ff02::%utun2/32                         fe80::19c4:e545:e84:a3bc%utun2  UmCI          utun2
ff02::%utun3/32                         fe80::f9fd:1490:c5f0:37ef%utun3 UmCI          utun3
```

---

### Tests

#### Listen for ping requests on  Mac mini:

1. Run `tcpdump -v host 192.168.1.231` on Mac mini
2. Run `ping -c 4 192.168.1.185` on MacBook
3. Mac mini output:

   ```
   tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
   tcpdump: listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), capture size 262144 bytes
   11:43:05.797487 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.1.185 tell 192.168.1.231, length 28
   11:43:05.797555 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.1.185 is-at 3c:22:fb:a8:43:ed (oui Unknown), length 28
   11:43:05.814090 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 4572, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
       192.168.1.231 > 192.168.1.185: ICMP echo request, id 40459, seq 0, length 64
   11:43:06.734317 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 42401, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
       192.168.1.231 > 192.168.1.185: ICMP echo request, id 40459, seq 1, length 64
   11:43:07.722478 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 36241, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
       192.168.1.231 > 192.168.1.185: ICMP echo request, id 40459, seq 2, length 64
   11:43:08.726554 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59095, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
       192.168.1.231 > 192.168.1.185: ICMP echo request, id 40459, seq 3, length 64
   ```

MacBook got no responses, all 4 requests timed out but as you can see mac mini got all requests and seems to even respond to ARP but ICMP is left without a response.

#### Disabling IPv6

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393113/cannot-ping-ipv4-address-but-ipv6-ping-works) gave me an idea it may be caused by Ipv6 so I ran `networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi` on both machines which caused no changes, so I enabled it back.

#### Setting a manual IP for Mac mini

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2554739?answerId=12153616022#12153616022) suggests that if I set the IP of mac mini to something else in the DHCP pool it may do something but it didn't (I tried `192.168.1.230` and `192.168.1.232`), so I put auto address back.

#### Disable other network interfaces

[Reverse Path Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32126202/6166627) seems extremely close to what I have but it's about Linux and [Mac OS treats this differently](https://serverfault.com/questions/711463/how-can-i-disable-reverse-path-filter-rp-filter-in-mac). I didn't spend much time on this but I thought it's related to the machine being confused with network interfaces, so I disabled all of them except the `192.168.*` on the mac mini but it didn't fix the problem.

#### Try a different router

I tried connecting the MacBook and the Mac Mini to my android phone's Wi-Fi hotspot but the situation is the same.

#### Connect via cable

I tried connecting the Mac Mini via ethernet cable directly into the router and nothing changed.

---

Hopefully, we can find a solution and it will even help somebody else in the future.

Comment: Code formatting should be done by selecting your code [or in this case report] section & hitting Ctrl/k [not Cmd, ctrl]. It's too hard to try undo your "quote with spoilers" format, otherwise I'd have done it, but it loses the new lines. Simpler if you could copy/paste again from your source.

Comment: @Tetsujin alright, if you insist, I translated spoilers to code blocks with ```. I just thought it'd be cleaner with spoilers

Comment: I don't 'insist', it's simply convention. Thanks for updating it.

Comment: On the mini, could you check if the "Enable stealth mode" is checked? I've seen that you turned off the firewall, but maybe this functionality sticks? So you'll probably have to enable the firewall on the mini to [see what the status](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110355/24324) is of the stealth mode checkbox.
Also, do you have Little Snitch or some other similar application on the mini? 
[This other question might be worth to check](https://superuser.com/q/541961/141595). It's not the same but perhaps relevant?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke thanks! Stealth mode is already disabled, `/etc/hosts` is just `ASCII text`, and I don't have Little Snitch installed but it wouldn't be a problem to install, not sure if it'll help though

Comment: @Sam Like what Tetsujin said, you are really over detailing this question and your formatting doesn’t help. I edited to remove your use of HTML. But here is my BIG question: You posted all of this yet you cannot provide basics such as what make/model fo router you are using and even what make and model of MacBook and Mac mini you are using let alone what macOS versions are running on each? Voting to close until the actual basics can be added and — and I don’t know if this is possible — if all the other excessive networking dumps can be trimmed down. I highly doubt that info is needed.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 well on most other questions I looked at while searching for solution people asked for routing tables. Perhaps, ifconfig is redundant but tcpdump shows an important point as well. I can remove ifconfig and add stuff you asked for

Comment: @Sam I’m not trying to dictate what you post, but what I am saying is this is most likely an issue with your router and you are providing all the information in the world *except* for basics. That is what is frustrating here. I cannot imagine anyone can help answer this question without the bare basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! The root cause was  `/Library/Extensions/cpfw.kext` - an extension added by my VPN software (Endpoint Security VPN). Once I removed it from that folder, the ping started working again!

Turns out this file is some kind of a firewall and the VPN works even without it.

For more troubleshooting details see [the post in the Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251991403).